# Telerik Report Viewer don't work with jquery async: false

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, telerik-reporting

I am using jQuery 1.11.0 in my project. I have changed ajaxSetting. I did `async:!0` instead of `async:!1` because my `remote validation` was working unexpectedly. This change didn't bother me anywhere but in Telerik Reporting. Due to this change `Telerik Reporting` don't load.

Is there anything I do any telerik reporting so that it load asyncronously and works perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after long troubleshooting I am able to solve this issue. Actually I did change in jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js. I reverted changes in jQuery 1.11.0.
I set async false only for remote validation. I did following chnages(in bold letters):

`b.add("remote",["url",`**`"asynx"`**`,"type","additionalfields"],function(b){var d={url:b.params.url,`**`async:false`**`,type:b.params.type||"GET",data:{}},e=h(b.element.name);a.each(j(b.params.additionalfields||b.element.name),function(i,h){var c=g(h,e);d.data[c]=function(){return a(b.form).find(":input").filter("[name='"+f(c)+"']").val()}});c(b,"remote",d)});`